# SmartGWT - ordered view of values in comboboxitem

Tags: java, smartgwt

I'm using Java7 and SmartGWT 3.1. Having the following code I encountered that the values are not displayed in the order I put them into.

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> insertOrdered = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
for (MyEnum me : MyEnum.values()) {
  insertOrdered.put(me.getId(), me.getMyName());
}
ComboBoxItem cbi = new ComboBoxItem();
cbi.setValueMap(insertOrdered);
```

the ID's are not ordered (neither ascending nor descending). But, this shouldn't matter, because if I'm not totally mistaken, `LinkedHashMap` orders with respect to insertion. Just to be sure I checked the JavaDoc again (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) and that's the case.

Why is the `ComboBoxItem` ignoring my ordering? Is there any other way to achieve ordering in a `ComboBoxItem`?

Comment: I don't think the code you've provided is a working example because as per my knowledge, ComboboxItem of SmartGWT takes only `LinkedHashMap<String, String>` as valueMap & not `LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>`.

Comment: it is working, it converts it internally when calling cbi.setValueMap (key.toString). but I also tried with LinkedHashMap<String, String>, no difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Javadoc of LinkedHashMap states:

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Even though, I would agree that the order that they appear should be the order that they are declared in the enum as stated by [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html). If you are having problems with LinkedHashMap ans you really want to ensure this order, perhaps you might want to try setting the values with the [variable argument list method](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/FormItem.html#setValueMap%28java.lang.String...%29). You will essentially change it to an array, it might be undesired but it could potentially solve your issue.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(MyEnum me: MyEnum.values()){
    list.add(me.getMyName());
 }

 ComboBoxItem cbi = new ComboBoxItem();
 cbi.setValueMap(list.toArray(new String[list.size()]));
```

Comment: thanks, I should read more carefully. the _variable argument list method_ works, thanks. the problem I have with this approach though is, that I lose the mapping to the key of the value. but I guess I'll have to live with it. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check if you are setting setSortField somewhere in your code. If you set the following:

```
 setSortField("null");
```

on the *ComboBoxItem* it will remove any sorting you may have and will keep the sort order of the backing LinkedHashMap.

Answer (score 0):

Use this operation the ComboxItem

```
ComboxItem cb = new ComboxItem();
cb.setSortField(SortDirection.ASCENDING.compareTo(SortDirection.ASCENDING));
```